# Show the different value from a database field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have this content of my MySQL database column:

```
+-------+
|Status |
+-------+
|       | // empty
|       | // empty
|Reject |
|reject |
+-------+
```

I have some condition for this `Status`, so the user can see the judgement of this case:

1. If result `Reject`(automatically if select item) or `reject`(some users type this after edit data ) echo Reject
2. If result `empty` or 'Accept' or 'accept` echo Accept

I have try this :

```
if($row['Status'] == "Reject"){
                echo "Reject";
                }
        elseif($row['Status'] == "reject"){
                echo "Reject";
                }
        else{
                echo "Accept";
                }
```

But, it's always echoing `Accept`. Cause the result of the query below is `empty`:

```
SELECT COUNT(Serial_number) AS n, SUM(S) AS S,SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B, SUM(C) AS C,
        ROUND((((SUM(S)*1)+(SUM(A)*1)+(SUM(B)*0.4)+(SUM(C)*0.1))/COUNT(Serial_number)*1000000),0) AS PPM,
        Status
        FROM inspection_report WHERE Model LIKE 'MDV-Z700D' AND Lot_no LIKE '010A' 
        AND Line LIKE 'FA 21' AND Range_sampling ='177X0001-177X0100' GROUP BY Range_sampling
```

Result :

```
n   S   A   B   C   PPM    Status
20  0   1   0   0   50000             //this empty status make echo = Accept
```

If using `GROUP_CONCAT(Status)` result is `,,Reject,reject`.So, how to echo each condition refer to 2 case above ?

---

Note : I want if inside that column have reject value the result echo reject even I have a lot of accept value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the `Status` is `NULL`, you can use `COALESCE`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(Status,'Accept'))
```

but if it's an empty string `''`, make use of `inline IF statement`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(if(Status = '' or Status = 'accept', 'Accept', Status))
```

**UPDATE**

```
IF(LOCATE('Reject',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(Status = '' or Status = 'accept', 'Accept', Status))) > 0, 'REJECT', 'ACCEPT')
```

Comment: Please take a look at my additional information. Actually I'm just need a single result. I'm using `GROUP_concat` just to show you that I have reject value inside my column.So, if found Reject inside that column, the result must be reject.

Comment: you have mentioned that if one on list is `Reject` then the whole result will be `Reject`, right? see my updated answer. Also [SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7bcc/1)

Comment: ok, it works, but I have two types of reject : Reject and reject. How to mention it inside this query?

Comment: so you mean `Reject` is different from `reject`?

Comment: no, i mean sometimes client type Reject or reject, if using this query could it detect the reject as Reject, if so it's no problem. but, if another case that inside the column just mention reject no Reject, whether this query still can use?